# Crashed: com.apple.main-thread EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS 0x0000000000000000

Tags: ios, flutter

On crashlytics dashboard i noticed a crash report with the log below but did not notice that on the app.

#### Environment

- iOS 15
- flutter 2.5

#### Logs

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  ???                            0x184df41a0 (Missing)
1  heic_to_jpg                    0x103043b40 $s11heic_to_jpg20SwiftHeicToJpgPluginC8register4withySo07FlutterH9Registrar_p_tFZ + 108
2  heic_to_jpg                    0x103043b40 $s11heic_to_jpg20SwiftHeicToJpgPluginC8register4withySo07FlutterH9Registrar_p_tFZ + 108
3  heic_to_jpg                    0x103043d34 $s11heic_to_jpg20SwiftHeicToJpgPluginC8register4withySo07FlutterH9Registrar_p_tFZTo + 56
4  heic_to_jpg                    0x103043abc +[HeicToJpgPlugin registerWithRegistrar:] + 76
5  Runner                         0x102c6be9c +[GeneratedPluginRegistrant registerWithRegistry:] + 81 (GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m:81)
6  Runner                         0x102c6c15c AppDelegate.application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:) + 12 (AppDelegate.swift:12)
7  Runner                         0x102c6c408 @objc AppDelegate.application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:) + 184 (<compiler-generated>:184)
8  ???                            0x182a2f3bc (Missing)
.
.
.
29 ???                            0x190e26b1c (Missing)
30 libdispatch.dylib              0x18011a2f0 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
31 libdispatch.dylib              0x1800bcf38 _dispatch_block_invoke_direct$VARIANT$mp + 220
43 Runner                         0x102c6c57c main + 6 (AppDelegate.swift:6)
```

Can anyone describe what this crash is? and why is related to a plugin?

Comment: Can you symbolicate your crash log ? Then show corresponding code.

Comment: @PtitXav what do you mean by **symbolicate**?

Comment: Look at : [adding identifiable symbol names to a crash report](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/adding-identifiable-symbol-names-to-a-crash-report)